# Using fields added by form events for collection items in symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

**Scenario**: I have to create an offer for customers. Each offer contains a list of items referring to products in the database. Those products may have different variants / options that affect pricing (which is calculated dynamically on change - no problem here). In my form, there is an autocomplete for product names which adds items assigned to the selected product to the collection.

**Problem**: When working with collections, symfonys way to handle adding items are prototypes. Unfortunately this process is handled completely on client side and thus there is no context given that could trigger a form event to add the product-dependent fields.

I have a few solutions that could solve this problem, but I wonder if there is kind of a best practice for this issue?

**Solution 1: Autosubmit form after selecting a product**

This is the simplest solution since after creating a new item with a product on server-side I have no issues working with form events and could add fields as needed. However the form would reload everytime, which is not so good from an UX point of view.

**Solution 2: Don't use prototype and create form for an unpersistent dummy-entity on serverside.**

This would be a little more complex. When adding a product, a server side script would create an item with that product assigned and create a form for that. There are a few issues with this e.g. regarding form ids / field names I think. This is currently my prefered solution.

**Solution 3: Rendering all fields possible and dynamically hide them if not needed (impossible)**

This is not possible as the fields are too dynamic for this. There is even a one-to-many association between the items and further options that need to be rendered. So knowing the product context is a must.

Resources:

[An 8 year old github issue for this topic](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4367)

Comment: Can't you override the default js for `CollectionType` as in [this plugin](https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/) to retrieve the new row server-side?

Comment: Yes I could, this would be equal to my suggested solution #2 I think. But there is still a problem with the IDs of the returned form paths that need to be replaced. I know how I could do it, but as stated in the question maybe there is some kind of best practice or experience from someone who already implemented sth like this

Comment: You can use your first option but use ajax request to submit your form and after create your entity, update only the part of html you need with a cool loading progress. I do this for project, this work as expected.

Comment: If this were me I'd use solution 1 but update the front end with AJAX instead of full page reloads. -- Your returned template from the controller doesn't need to contain the whole layout, it could just be the form (or part of it) returned as the "html" key of a `JsonResponse`.